# Is the term "golden point" used much in badminton?

Tags: terminology, badminton

From Wikipedia

> If the score reaches 20-all, then the game continues until one side gains a two-point lead (such as 24–22), except when there is a tie at 29-all, in which the game goes to a golden point. Whoever scores this point will win.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badminton#Scoring

Is golden point a commonly used term when talking about badminton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Golden point* is the sports-independent way of referring to a point that immediately ends the match (or game). The term is usually used in sports where scoring is rare. In badminton and other racket sports, scoring (by winning a rally) is extremely common.
The term would be understood in a badminton context.

However, its actual usage is rare. For example, if you look at the [google search results for "golden point" on badmintoncentral.com (probably the largest badminton forum)](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Abadmintoncentral.com+"golden+point"), you'll see that there are only 5 search results, and only a single result which uses the term *golden point* for 29-all. It's probably being used more by people familiar with Rugby or Australian-rules football.

A much more common term would be *gamepoint* or *matchpoint*, for when a player has the opportunity to win the game or match. Both terms are very commonly used, in informal speech as well as the [official vocabulary](https://extranet.bwfbadminton.com/docs/document-system/81/1466/1470/Section%204.1.5%20-%20Vocabulary%20-3.pdf).
After all, in the official scoring system (and KO tournaments being quite common), it does not matter if you win 30-29 or 21-0; it's much more important if that wins you the game or the match.

Also, golden points are rare in badminton, at least with the 3x21_30 scoring system: Out of 144674 games in a database I had laying around (all the official games in [leagues in NRW 2018/2019](http://www.tournamentsoftware.com/sport/league?id=95E4D9B3-8ECF-4B90-AC3E-3187852F20FD)), only 32 – 0.02% or **1 in 4500** – ended in 30-29. In top-level sports the scores may be closer, but many players have played only a couple of games to 30-29 in their life, and some none at all.